# Better way to accomplish simple task in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, events

So, I have a small test for school where I need to DISABLE three radio buttons which are in a panel in the least amount of possible code WHILE the contents of two text boxes are empty. As soon as both textboxes are filled, I enable the panel.

The below solution obviously works with one single text box, but what happens with two?
I know I can override each button KeyPress and check both text boxes at the same time. But I wanted to go fancy. The problem is I think there is no way I can solve this problem like this.

Or is it?

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub vacios(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Panel1.Enabled = (sender.Text <> "")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler txtNombre.KeyPress, AddressOf vacios
        AddHandler txtApellido.KeyPress, AddressOf vacios
    End Sub
End Class
```

#### Note - I know I can do this But I wanted to be fancy.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub txtNombre_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNombre.TextChanged
        Panel1.Enabled = (txtNombre.Text <> "" And txtApellido.Text <> "")
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtApellido_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtApellido.TextChanged
        Panel1.Enabled = (txtNombre.Text <> "" And txtApellido.Text <> "")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can use one TextChanged event handler since the code is identical.  Just move the Handles clause from one to the other.

Comment: @Plutonix nice idea. Thanks!

Comment: You should put `Option Strict On` at the top of the code file - `sender.Text` wont compile because `Object` does not have a text property.  Those sloppy implicit conversions are a VBism not in most languages.  BTW editing the Handles clause like that is the design time version of the AddHandler thing you do in the first snippet.  It is not an override though in the normal sense of the word

Comment: thanks for all your comments @Plutonix

Comment: I personally like the vbisms, because I can concentrate on creativity and leave the IDE inferring my intentions. What if the other languages are WRONG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VB you can have multiple handles for the same sub just by adding "Handles Object1.Event,Object2.Event ..." at the end.

here an example of what i would do in this case

```
 Public Class Form1

        Private Sub panel1TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtApellido.TextChanged,txtNombre.TextChanged
            Panel1.Enabled = (txtNombre.Text <> String.Empty And txtApellido.Text <> String.Empty)
        End Sub
    End Class
```